# Magento 2 - How to change Mega Menu sort order in store views alphabetical for each store view?

Tags: magento2, megamenu

maybe one of you is facing the same issue and has solved it already.

We are using the Mega Menu for Magento 2. We have 5 store views (German, English, Spanish, Italian, French)

Our default language shop and store view is german.

Now I sort my categories alphabetical for german in the backend which then is reflected in the sort order in the mega menu in the front end as well.

But this sort order of the categories is then taken for all other languages as well and mixed up. I have not found a way to sort each store views categories alphatebically individually.

How would you solve this? Is a styling via CSS or such possible for the other languages than German possibly?

Maybe one of the experts out there has a hint.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different root category for each store.

Apply it to particular store from **Admin > Stores > Edit Store > Root Category**

[image]

Set different root category for each store you can manage sort order of category

Comment: Hi Prashant, thank you for the hint. Having a blank installation and starting from the scratch this sounds perfect. But as I have filled already all info in my store views and store view pathes are also associated to products which are all imported already, does that not create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you got the answer you needed for this but just in case anyone else stumbles across this issue, here is my solution.

You need to check what scope you're altering when changing category sorting
[image]

If you're on "All Store Views" then it will re-arrange them in all views.

Also, as you have already said, if you're re-arranging your default store then you need to make sure that the "use default value" button within all dropdowns of your other store views is disabled so any changes you make aren't reflected across the board.

[image]